# $y^2=x^3+1$ and its solution in terms of Eisenstein numbers

Tags: number-theory

Consider the following MO question: [Is there an elementary way to find the integer solutions to  $x^2-y^3=1?$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/39561)

In the second proof in his answer to this MO post, Franz Lemmermeyer", considering the case when the numbers are coprime, writes the following entry:

a) $x+1=±a^2$, $x+ρ=(−ρ)^e(a+bρ)^2$, $x+ρ^2=(−ρ^2)^e(a+bρ^2)^2$. Since $ρ=(1+ρ)^2$ is a square, we can subsume the powers of ρ into the square and find $x+ρ=±(a+bρ)^2$ and $x+ρ^2=±(a+bρ^2)^2$

Firstly, could you explain to me what this "e" means, it is obviously not an exponent, but why does it stand next to the reversible element?

Further, I do not understand the transition with entering the degree under the square. If you think like the author of the post, it turns out: $x+ρ=((-1)^e)(1+ρ)^{2e}(a+bρ)^2$ but this is by no means: $x+ρ=±(a+bρ)^2$ or am I thinking wrong? Same with the second line.

And thirdly, I do not really understand why the author, considering the case when the factors are divided by 1-ρ, chose exactly 3 as an element, divisible by 1-ρ (in fact, even by $(1-ρ)^2$). Why selects the smallest element with this property: $x+1= ±3a^2$. And why do we take exactly $(1-ρ^2)$, and not just (1-ρ) in the case when we consider: $x+ρ^2=(1-ρ^2)(a+bρ^2)^2$

I would be incredibly grateful if someone could answer my questions!

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/a/70245/500241

Comment: Five solutions are $(x,y)=(-1,0)$, $(0, \pm{1})$, and $(2, \pm{3})$. Are they the only solutions?

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang Yes, F. Lemmermeyer proves it.

Comment: Anne, Thanks for your help with the link, answering your question since the gcd of two derivatives of Eisenstein numbers is either 1-ρ or 1

Comment: Ohh, I'm sorry, I made a mistake, I meant to write arbitrary numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

($ρ$ is a primitive cube root of unity.)

1. This $e$ is an exponent (wlog $e\in\{-2,-1,0,1,2,3\}$), so that $(-\rho)^e$ denotes an arbitrary unit in $\Bbb Z[\rho],$ unit up to which $x+\rho$ is a square. The same $e$ then naturally appears in the expression of the conjugate element $x+\rho^2.$
2. $x+ρ=(-1)^e((1+ρ)^e(a+bρ))^2=(-1)^e(a'+b'ρ)^2$ for some integers $a',b'$ (easily computable from $a,b,e$), and the conjugate $x+ρ^2$ is then naturally equal to $(a'+b'ρ^2)^2.$ F.L. simply renamed $a,b$ these new integers $a',b'.$
3. If $1-ρ$ divides the integer $x+1,$ so does its norm $(1-ρ)(1-ρ^2)=3,$ whence the $3$ in $x+1=\pm3a^2$ in F.L.'s case (b). In this second case, implicitely, the previous manipulation on squares and change of integer variables $a,b$ is already done, which permits to write $x+ρ=\pm(1-ρ)(a+bρ)^2.$ Like in 1. above, the conjugate $x+ρ^2$ is then equal to $\pm(1-ρ^2)(a+bρ^2)^2.$

Edit: "conjugation" on $\Bbb Z[\rho]$ is the restriction of the usual conjugation on $\Bbb C,$
$$f(a+b\rho)=\overline{a+b\rho}=a+b\rho^2=a+b(-1-\rho),$$
but can also be shown directly to be an automorphism of $\Bbb Z[\rho]:$

- $f$ is bijective and even involutive: $(f\circ f)(a+b\rho)=f(a-b-b\rho)=a-b-b(-1-\rho)=a+b\rho;$
- $f$ obviously commutes with $+;$
- it also commutes with multiplication:

  - $$f((a+b\rho)(c+d\rho))=f(ac+(ad+bc)\rho+bd(-1-\rho)=ac-bd+(ad+bc-bd)(-1-\rho),$$
  - $$f(a+b\rho)f(c+d\rho)=(a+b\rho^2)(c+d\rho^2)=ac+(ad+bc)\rho^2+bd\rho^4=ac+(ad+bc)(-1-\rho)+bd\rho,$$hence both are equal.

Comment: Many thanks for the explanation, I thought that he redesignated them, the question is as follows, conditionally in the first case e=1, x+ρ=±((1+ρ)(a+bρ))², in the second e  =2, x+ρ²=±((1+ρ)²(a+bρ²)², and how then should one rename so that a' and b' match in both cases, as F.L did?

Comment: And yet I did not understand why we take exactly (1-ρ²), and not just (1-ρ).  We need to show that the number is divisible by (1-ρ), so x+ρ²=±(1-ρ)(a+bρ²)², why is it not?  Sorry for my probably stupid questions, I'm still in school, but I'm fond of mathematics, mainly number theory :)

Comment: If $x+\rho=P(\rho)$ where $P$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients, then $x+\rho^2=P(\rho^2).$ This is because of the automorphism of the ring $\Bbb Z[\rho]$ which maps $\rho$ to $\rho^2.$ " in the first case e=1, x+ρ=±((1+ρ)(a+bρ))², in the second e =2, x+ρ²=±((1+ρ)²(a+bρ²)²": no, $e$ is the same for x+ρ and x+ρ², and $e$ may be any integer between, say, -2 and +3.

Comment: $1-ρ$ obviously divides $1-ρ²,$ but the converse is true: $1-ρ=(1-ρ²)(-ρ).$

Comment: 1) e=2, x+ρ=(1+ρ)⁴(a+bρ)², ((1+ρ)²(a+bρ))²=(ρ(a+bρ))²=(-  b+(a-b)ρ)², x+ρ²=((1+ρ)⁴(a+bρ²))², ((1+ρ)⁴(a+bρ²))²=(ρ(a+bρ²))  ²=(b+aρ)², How to denote a', b' so that they match for x+ρ=(a'+b'ρ)² and for x+ρ²=(a'+b'ρ²)²  ?

Comment: 2) The specific question is why we cannot take x+p²=±(1-p)(a+bρ²)², but write x+ρ²=±(1-ρ²)(a+bρ²)²?

Comment: 1) You did some mistake in the calculation of $x+ρ².$ In fact when $e=2,$ $(a',b')=\pm(-b,a-b)$ matches for both x+ρ=(a'+b'ρ)² and x+ρ²=(a'+b'ρ²)². In fact it is useless to redo the calculation for $x+ρ².$ By the automorphism mentionned in a previous comment, if x+ρ=(a'+b'ρ)² then automatically x+ρ²=(a'+b'ρ²)²

Comment: 2) We cannot take x+ρ²=±(1-ρ)(a+bρ²)² because we already took x+ρ=±(1-ρ)(a+bρ)², and this implies (by the automorphism mentionned in a previous comment) x+ρ²=±(1-ρ²)(a+bρ²)², not x+ρ²=±(1-ρ)(a+bρ²)².

Comment: That's it, thank you so much, I finally figured it out) I'm very glad that there are such people on the forum who are ready to answer even stupid questions;))

Comment: And exactly the last thing I would like to ask on this question, how do we understand that an automorphism of the ring of Eisenstein numbers maps ρ to ρ²?  Does this fact need to be proven or does it follow from some property of the ring of integers and automorphisms in it?  I don't know much about linear algebra :)

Comment: You can just define this map by $f(a+b\rho)=a+b\rho^2$ ($\forall a,b\in\Bbb Z$), and check that it is a ring automorphism. Alternatively, simply notice that $f$ is the restriction of the conjugation automorphism of the complex numbers.

Comment: Can you please show how to check the automorphism for f(a+bρ), if it's not difficult for you?  Sorry again for such stupid questions.  I understand that this is super obvious to you and most likely you have no interest in answering such simple questions.